# Testing custom style widgets with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric

Trying a unit test with Robolectric 3.0 that use custom style in values/styles.xml looks like `<style name="EditTextWhite" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">` and apply that style into `EditText` looks like `android:theme="@style/EditTextWhite"`.

In testing class:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class RegisterActivityTest {
    RegisterActivity mRegisterActivity;
    EditText edtName;

    @Before
    public void init() {    
        mRegisterActivity=Robolectric.setupActivity(RegisterActivity.class); // Line 1
        edtName = (EditText) mRegisterActivity.findViewById(R.id.edtName); // Line 2
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    public void register_Failed_PasswordMismatch() {
        // ...
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        mRegisterActivity = null;
    }
}
```

When I run the test, running the test didn't finished even I have waiting a few minutes. That's mean **Line 2** never executed because Line 1 still executing.

So, I try with remove `android:theme="@style/EditTextWhite"` in `EditText` is successfully test.

How can I unit test the custom styled widgets using Robolectric 3.0?

Comment: Is it your first run of test? Robolectric downloads AOSP code first time that it starts. Can you run tests in command line, what do you see?

Comment: It is not first run. Robolectric already downloaded AOSP code. [This link](https://gist.github.com/infinityzero/bdf34d9d7c9de18d0a09) is detail logs.

Comment: We have a similar setup that works for us. I see just one warning in gradle output `E/Typeface: Error opening /system/etc/fonts.xml`. Can you run same command line with `-d` and `-s` options

Comment: [This link](https://gist.github.com/infinityzero/21b9122f1f503ce801d3) is debug logs.